# progressBar dialog not counting upwards from 0, just appears for a second

Tags: android, onclick, progressdialog

I have a progressBar dialog for when I click my button, the dialog appears and a message appears but the progress sticks at 0% and then goes to the next activity instead of going from 0%-100% as expected. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
package win.jay.todo.list;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Welcome extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }

    //Onclick - go to Tasks
    public void doStuff(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Tasks.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        progress.setMessage("Finding tasks...");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.show();

        final int totalProgressTime = 100;

        final Thread t = new Thread(){

           @Override
           public void run(){

              int jumpTime = 5;
              while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime){
                 try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    jumpTime += 5;
                    progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }

           }

       };
       t.start();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the ProgressDialog? Just killing time while your Tasks Activity loads?

Comment: Exactly yes, the user will see this dialog for a few seconds while the tasks load, when its finished the task activity will now be showing all ready for usage.

Comment: This is generally not a good approach. I suggest using an AsyncTask in your Tasks Activity instead. There, you can show a ProgressDialog in onPreExecute, load the tasks in doInBackground, and hide the ProgressDialog/show the tasks in onPostExecute.

Comment: @cygery Thanks for the tip, I'll have a look into that approach